# How to avoid and predict Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, memory

So ,if i have a `List<Bitmap> myBitmaps` where i should store lot of Bitmaps token from a DataBase ,and it might a Out of Memory Exception ,how can i avoid that .

Should i store a bunch of Images at Hard Drive ,than load another Bunch after first bunch Processing etc.

Another case is if i load a Base64 and encode to String and String to Base64 against large amount of data how can i achieve it without causing Out of Memory Exception ,and how can i predict if there is going to be a Out of Memory Exception in both cases .

PS : If someone offers a solution please could it explain if it's slows Performance and why .

Comment: What's “Memory Out Of Range Exception”? Did you mean [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) or [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx)? They are completely different.

Comment: @svick updated Out of Memory Exception i mismatched it sory

Comment: And why do you have large amounts of data encoded using Base64? That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Also, the two question seem to be completely unrelated. You should ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of it, it seems like the `Bitmaps` are large and it will be impractical to store them all in memory. If you are doing bulk operations on it then swapping to disk will certainly cause performance degradation but given that in real world you are working with hardware limits there are no options.

You might be able to cache certain metadata about the bitmaps in memory to speedup operations. Another option is to cache entire bitmaps in memory and go to the disk when data is not available in core memory.

Exactly which ones you cache will again depend on usage pattern. Consider using `WeakReference` as well.

Base64 conversion for large data can be trivially converted to an [online algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-line_algorithm), converting small amount of data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer storing such a (possible) mass of data in a database. The performance with a database depends on the database, the hardware and the connection to the database.

Comment: yes you prefer and i do ,but i have cases where i need to load large amount of data into a List<T> .

Comment: @Cody: Then you take care of the OutOfMemoryException in a try catch block, don't you?

Comment: the question is not that Simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmaps are so big, you could just load them one by one. Every time load just one bitmap, process it, don't forget to `Dispose()` it and then go on another bitmap.

If doing lots of SQL queries like this makes a difference for you, load and process the bitmaps in bunches of N (where N depends on your specific circumstances). There is no need to save them to the disk, that's what the database is for.